# Select column if specific type of child record exists otherwise fallback

Tags: sql-server, query

I got a table named "Order", an order has multiple child records in the table "OrderStatus".
The orderstatus contains steps following the progress of an order. The orderstatus contains a datetime field holding a timestamp when the specific status was finialized.

I need to get the datestamp of a specific type of status (say XX) -IF- it exists for the order, otherwise fallback to the date of status YY.

I've set up a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=078d09c494bdfd18374bdf81d61d19a5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this solves your problem.

I'm joining to the `OrderStatus` table twice.  One using a regular inner join looking for `Status` = 'YY' (I'm assuming there will always be one) and the other join is a left join looking for `Status` = 'XX'.  Then, I use `COALESCE` to choose the first non-null value.

```
--Demo setup
Declare @Orders table (id int);
insert into @Orders(id) values(1);
insert into @Orders(id) values(2);

Declare @OrderStatus table (id int, OrderStatus char(2), Time_Stamp datetime);
insert into @OrderStatus(id, OrderStatus,Time_Stamp) values(1,'YY','2019-01-01');
insert into @OrderStatus(id, OrderStatus,Time_Stamp) values(1,'XX','2019-02-01');

insert into @OrderStatus(id, OrderStatus,Time_Stamp) values(2,'YY','2019-03-01');
insert into @OrderStatus(id, OrderStatus,Time_Stamp) values(2,'ZZ','2019-06-01');

--The solution - left join to the OrderStatus twice - one looking for XX and one looking for YY
SELECT o.id
    ,coalesce(osXX.Time_Stamp, osYY.time_stamp) AS Time_Stamp   --Choose the first non-null value
FROM @Orders o
JOIN @OrderStatus osYY
    ON osYY.id = o.id
        AND osYY.OrderStatus = 'YY'     --Find the YY Order Status - assume there will always be one
LEFT JOIN @OrderStatus osXX
    ON osXX.id = o.id
        AND osXX.OrderStatus = 'XX';    --Left Join - Try to find an XX Order Status
```

---

```
| id | Time_Stamp              |
|----|-------------------------|
| 1  | 2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | 2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
```